# Searching on geolocation in the SoundCloud API?

Tags: api, geolocation, soundcloud

The [SoundCloud API](https://developers.soundcloud.com/docs/api/guide#search) allows you to search. Coordinates (lat/lng) seem to be stored as tags in the tag_list property for [tracks](https://developers.soundcloud.com/docs/api/reference#tracks). It seems I can filter on matching tags.

Can I use the SoundCloud API to find matching tracks with a geospatial bounding box or a centre with a radius?
Or can I only match coordinates exactly?

If the former, how?

Comment: So much for SoundCloud's claim that their techies are monitoring stackoverflow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [SoundCloud blog posts talking about mapping audio](http://soundcheck.soundcloud.com/audio/map-your-audio/) links to maps that don't open. For example:

http://maps.soundcloudlabs.com/?lat=32.47269502206151&lon=13.359375&maxOffset=50&zoom=3

Furthermore, I'm unable to add geotags to my files on SoundCloud. Adding them as tags and saving the file fails silently: Upon reopening the file for editing, the geotags do not show up.

Third, SoundCloud API calls for tracks do not seem to include geotags.

Fourth, searching for a geotag using the SoundCloud API consistently returns no results.

Therefore, it is safe to assume that SoundCloud no longer supports geocoding on their audio files.